# How to compare new password to old hashed password?

Tags: php, laravel, api, passwords

I have made a update current password API in laravel 8. It is changing my current password if I pass the new password as an argument. But problem is if I pass both passwords i.e old password and new password same. It still says password updated. I want to show an error message saying password should not be same. Here is my code of change password:

```
public function updatePassword(Request $request)
{
    $input = $request->validate([
        'old_password'=> 'string',
        'password'=> 'string'
    ]);
    if (Hash::check($input['old_password'], auth()->user()->password)) {
        $user = new User();
        $user = auth()->user();
        $user->password = bcrypt($input['password']);
        $user->save();

        return $this->success('Password Updated', $user);
    }
    return $this->error('Password should not be same');
}`
```

Comment: Are you using a framework, if so its best to specify which one

Comment: [The manual may help you a lot](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/hashing#verifying-that-a-password-matches-a-hash)

Comment: read my first line

Answer (score 3):

You already have old password in input.

```
if($input['password'] === $input['old_password']){
    return $this->error('Password should not be same');
}
```

Comment: It will not match my old password to the password which has been stored in my database

Comment: If it will not match old password - you must throw Unauthorised exception - check it with auth()->validate(['id' => auth()->id, 'password' => $input['old_password']])